# Add auto-increment column to an existing table and create foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, auto-increment

I am using SQL Server 2014. There are two tables `T1` and `T2` with relational data. These tables have more than 100000 rows.

`T1` has a primary key `ID` (`varchar`) and `T2` is mapped with this `ID` (`varchar`).

I want to add another auto increment column `AutoId` (`int`) to the table `T1`, and I want to add column `AutoId` to table `T2` as well.

Then I want to update `AutoId` in `T2` from `T1` based on the existing `ID`.

What is the easiest way to solve this?

Comment: hi trigger is bad solution in SQL Server because that add 14 byte data to sql server page for pointer of trigger best way is add on columns as IDENTITY (1,1) then write bulk update statement like second answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use trigger After Insert

```
This is for new Records

CREATE TRIGGER [schema_name.]trigger_name
ON table_name
AFTER  {[INSERT],[UPDATE],[DELETE]}
[NOT FOR REPLICATION]
AS
{sql_statements}
```

or its for one time  the best way is update :

```
This is for Old Records
update t2
set t2.ID2 = t1.ID2
 from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.id= t2.id
```

Comment: Update statement is not running correctly. This is the Correct one 
  UPDATE T2
  SET T2.[AutoId] = T1.[AutoId]
  FROM T2, T1
  WHERE T2.ManualId = T1.ManualId

Answer (score 1):

You can create AutoID using `IDENTITY` on T1 table even though it has `PRIMARY KEY` and `existing data`.

You can update that AutoID in T2 table using `JOIN` with ID `Primary key`.

Please check below query for your answer.

```
CREATE TABLE T1(ID VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY)

CREATE TABLE T2(T2ID INT IDENTITY, ID VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO T1(ID)
VALUES ('V1'),('V2'),('V3'),('V4'),('V5')

INSERT INTO T2(ID)
VALUES ('V1'),('V2'),('V3'),('V4'),('V5')

SELECT ID FROM T1
SELECT T2ID,ID FROM T2
Go

ALTER TABLE T1
ADD AutoID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
GO

ALTER TABLE T2
ADD AutoID INT
Go

SELECT ID,AutoID FROM T1
SELECT T2ID,ID, AutoID FROM T2
Go

UPDATE TT
SET TT.AutoID = T.AutoID
FROM T1 AS T
INNER JOIN T2 AS TT ON TT.ID = T.ID
GO

SELECT ID,AutoID FROM T1
SELECT T2ID,ID, AutoID FROM T2

DROP TABLE T1
GO
DROP TABLE T2
GO
```

[Demo](https://rextester.com/UQCB19781)